# Conductivity of Different Gasses

Tags: conductivity, gas

Hey what is the most conductive gas that can be easily found. and will lowering the pressure increase the conductivity?

Comment: I don't think you're going to find any conductive gas until you ionize some of its components. At which point it becomes a plasma, rather than a gas.

Comment: at which time it will emit photons - how ionic.

Comment: Thermally, electrically, acoustically,  what???

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38631/can-gases-conduct-electricity

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is off topic

Comment: @placeholder how is a question about electrical conductivity in a gas that's obviously intended for use in an electrical circuit the OP is engineering "off-topic" for an electrical engineering discussion?

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB read http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic , there is no attempt in contextualizing to the EE.SE requirements.

Comment: This question seems more in line with physics than electricity.

Comment: The only naturally (electrically) conductive gas is likely to contain its own ionising source, such as some percentage of radon or tritium. Thermal conductivity is a different matter and is almost independent of pressure, outside the high vacuum region.

Comment: @user3337902: "_... and will lowering the pressure increase the conductivity?_" Just think: "My gas is conducting so I'll lower the pressure and it will conduct some more and if I keep going until I've got a perfect vacuum the conduction will be at a maximum." Does that sound right?

Comment: "Gasses" by themselves are not an electrical or electronic device. Their main descriptions, methodologies and 'canon' is that of physics.

Answer (score 4):

In answer to part 1 of your question:

- Argon is readily available (check welding supply centers) and has about 1/5 the dielectric strength of air.
- Helium, also fairly available, has about 1/6.5 the dielectric strength of air.

In answer to part 2 of your question:
Yes, reduced pressures generally reduce the dielectric strength of gasses.

(note: Lower dielectric strength = less barrier to conductivity & once a gas's dielectric is "broken," the resulting arc creates a highly conductive plasma)

Further Reading:

- [Dielectric Strength of Some Gasses](http://www.tesla-coil.com/dielectricstrengthgas.htm)
- [Paschen's Law (effect of pressure & gap-length on diellectric breakdown voltage of gas)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paschen%27s_law)

Comment: But it should still be pointed out that: Gasses are not conductive in the traditional sense. They don't really conduct *at all* until you hit the dielectric breakdown voltage, then they become *REALLY* conductive real fast, they also emit light at this point.

Comment: @Tom ...and are technically converted from gas to plasma rapidly between corona-discharge phase & arc phase, at which point they cease being gasses & are converted into plasma. However, I don't think that's immediately relevant to EE discussion unless making a corona->arc sensing or triggering device (such as components of the arc/plasma speakers I'm currently designing circuits for).

Answer (score 1):

Gases have extremely low electrical conductivity, all of them. This is because they are basically a vacuum with "a few" electrically neutral molecules in it.

When you ionize such molecules by some mean (e.g. increasing the temperature) you obtain what is called a *plasma*, which you can imagine as gas made by ions and electrons.

In particular, if you have a gas container with electrodes in it, and you apply a voltage above a ceratin value, called *breakdown voltage* of the gas, you can ionize the gas (this technique has many applications in electrical engineering and applied physics).